# Are there known (slow boot) issues with Dell XPS17 (L702x) and Grub?

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, dell

I just received my Dell XPS17 and installed it as follows:

Partition 1: 100GB NTFS Windows 7
Partition 2:  16GB Swap
Partition 3: 100GB EXT4 Linux /
Partition 4: 536GB LUKS + NTFS Data

all four are primary partitions. I installed Windows Pro 64-bit first, then Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. With the Windows Bootloader in the MBR, the delay at the Dell boot splash was barely noticeable. After Grub was installed there, both Windows and Linux still boot smoothly from the Grub menu - but to get there from the splash screen it takes about 30-40 seconds. Is this a known issue with Grub/Dell BIOS/whatever and is there a solution? (Couldn't find anything directly related to my case, only if more than one HDD is used)

Best regards,
Frederic

Comment: I don't have issues on the same notebook with a dualboot. You could try to flash your BIOS to the latest version. Unplugging all storage devices (external hdd, usb stick) might work too.

Comment: Pardon me, I'm a bit confused. It's now slow to get the grub menu or after you get the grub menu to where you see the Windows spash screen, or after you see the splash screen to where you can login? By the way, 30-40 seconds to boot Windows or Ubuntu 12.04 is in line with my usual experience, but my computers aren't real fast.

Comment: @john-s-gruber Actually, the Dell boot splash was showing with a full bar for about 30-40 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just installed a second HDD in bay 2 - the problem is gone. No idea if that was actually the solution. Somebody over at the Dell forums (en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19449900/20108654.aspx) thought that booting might get delayed artificially after typing an incorrect BIOS password. I never set a password, though.

Otherwise, my only guess is that this was some it-just-happens-sometimes thing. Thanks for your help and ideas! If somebody else comes across the same problem, please try if inderting a second HDD solves your problem. I don't want to open the Laptop again just to check :-)